# why am I getting a routing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following a RoR tutorial and the routing file that was gererated in the tutorial is different to the one that was generated on my computer.  The one on the tutorial was

```
Lecture::Application.routes.draw.do
  get 'say/hello'
```

my file gererated

```
Rails.application.routes.draw.do
  get 'say/hello'
```

Does this make a difference because I am getting a routing error:

> Routing Error No route matches [GET] "/say/hello"

What is the reason for this?

Comment: what is the output of rake routes

Comment: I typed rake routes and got this :    Prefix Verb URI Pattern            Controller#Action
say_hello GET  /say/hello(.:format) say#hello

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please put the `rake route` output into your original question? formatting in comments is really hard to read... :P :) Note: the reason for the difference is probably a rails-version difference. What version does the tutorial say it uses? what version do you use?

Comment: how can I find the rake routes output?

Comment: the tutorial uses 4.0 I'm using 4 so is there a way to "convert" the code

Comment: open `rails console`, and type `rake routes` and paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where the route leads.
For example: ([Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html))

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'
```

or in your case:

```
get 'say/hello', to: 'say#hello'
```

The to formatting is 'controller_name#controller_action'

To define an action use:

```
def hello
  #This is my hello action
end
```

Comment: I tried "get 'say/hello', to: 'say#hello'" and got the same error

Comment: What is the name of your controller? And do you have the "hello" action defined?

Comment: controller is "say" and the action "hello" is defined in the controller. that's why I don't understand the error message. its saying there is no route but there IS a route there as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `say` controller and `hello` method in that controller,

change,

```
get 'say/hello', to: 'say#hello'
```

to,

```
get '/say/hello', to: 'say#hello'
```

Observe, `'/say/hello'`.

If you dont have that controller,

type `rake routes` in `rails console` and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb

get 'say/hello' => 'say#hello' #Here say is controller and hello is action

#controllers/say_controller.rb

class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

your controller file should be:

```
say_controller.rb

Class SayController < ApplicationController
  def hello
   puts 'hello there'
  end
end
```

your routes.rb file should contain:

```
routes.rb

get '/anything/you_want/', to 'say#hello'
```

this should do the trick